# String transforming with danger symbols

Tags: java, regex

I have the followings string:

```
String l = "1. [](a+b)\n2. (-(q)*<>(r))\n3. 00(d)\n4. (a+-b)";
String s = "1. [](a+b)\n2. 00(d)"
```

First string is a expresions list. Sencond string is a expresions subset of first string, but theirs number-ids aren't equals.

Then, I want to do this:

```
String l2 = "1. <b>[](a+b)</b>\n2. (-(q)*<>(r))\n3. <b>00(d)</b>\n4. (a+-b)";
```

`l2` is a transformation of `l` but with expressions marked. This marked expresions are contains in `s`. Note that originals strings have symbols as `(`, `[`, and so on 
What is better way to do it?

Comment: Just so I know what I'm looking at, what is a danger symbol?

Comment: Metacharacter `(`, `[`, and so on

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, your problem ist that

```
String.replaceAll(String, String)
```

doesn't work here, because the Characters `(`, `[`, `\`, have special meanings in regular expressions.

Maybe you could just use

```
String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)
```

Then you don't need to deal with regular expressions at all.

Comment: I know it. The regular expresion is the problem.

Comment: @isola009: Just wanted to acknowledge that using `replace()` should work fine.

Comment: @isola009: You do not need any regular expression to implement this. Just use replace().

Answer (score 0):

```
    String l = "1. [](a+b)\n2. (-(q)*<>(r))\n3. 00(d)\n4. (a+-b)";
    String s = "1. [](a+b)\n2. 00(d)";

    String[] a=l.split("\\n");
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        a[i]=a[i].split("\\d. ")[1];
    String[] b=s.split("\\n");
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        b[i]=b[i].split("\\d. ")[1];

    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
      l=l.replace(b[i], "<b>"+b[i]+"</b>");
```